# Laravel Sail Docker PHPMyAdmin : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

I have some trouble connecting to PHPMyAdmin. So I always get the following message.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

I looked for a solution on Google, but the answers I've found don't work for me. For example, I can connect to my database in the command line and migrate my tables but not through PHPMyAdmin.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${HMR_PORT:-8080}:8080'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
        environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            PMA_PORT: 3306
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=todo_list_app
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same Error on my Raspberry-Pi. I fixed this by changing the phpmyadmin Imagename from `arm64v8/phpmyadmin:latest` to `arm64v8/phpmyadmin:5.2`. I would recommend try to use `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:5.2` or another specific version of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thank you it works. I didn't think about changing the version...
Do you know why it isn't working on the last version ?

Comment: Can't really help with that, but I would recommend to give this blog a read - https://vsupalov.com/docker-latest-tag/

Comment: I just realized. You asked why isn't it working on the last version. But that's not the problem. For clarification: The last released version of the Image works fine. It is just the Image **tagged** with latest. A weird anomaly reveals if you compare the as latest tagged version and the latest image with a version tag. Last time I checked they had the exact same size.